# Add Text in Hover Zoom Card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I wanna add text in front of card hover zoom. But it will show behind the zoom hover

```html
      <div style="margin-top: 50px;" class="container imgzoom">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-evenly">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <p class="text1">Lisbon, Portugal</p>
            <img data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#2" src="img/2.jpg" class="img-fluid      cardzoom rounded-2" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```css
.cardzoom{
  transition: .3s;
}

.cardzoom:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1)
}
```

Can you fix this guys?

Comment: I do not understand your question,which is the text you want to add?this is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pure-js-html-julof5?file=/index.html) to demonstrate you question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.card-group {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.card-group img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.card-group p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  margin-top: 50%;
  left: -10%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.card-group:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="margin-top: 50px;" class="container imgzoom">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-evenly">
    <div class="col-md-2 card-group">
      <p class="text1">Lisbon, Portugal</p>
      <img data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#2" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
        class="img-fluid      cardzoom rounded-2" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: text 1 without css?

Comment: @FahryIbrahim `text1` has css, but I've used it on the `<p>` tag, if you need you can change that to `.card-group p.text1` to target only `text1`.